# oracle how to lower hwm? I want to get my filesystem space back

Tags: oracle

I want more file system space. so I truncate all tables in oracle ,but the higher water mark still so high, I shrink my tables; I had google it ,shrink only cut dowen the space higher than hwm It reduce some space, but It help less.and I find that tablespace is only used 1% space.how can I free the space in my file system.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to export the database at user level using exp. Then drop and recreate the user. Then do an import. This should free up some space.

You can also use alter database datafile to reduce one of your datafiles (these are the physical files on your hard drive used by the db).

There is a great overview of how to reclaim datafile space in this article. TL DR - export, drop user, alter datafile, import.

http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/reclaiming-unused-space.php

Comment: I have used alter database datafile cmd, It free some datafiles.but It only free about 1G that higer than hwm. I still have about 13G space do not freed.My datafiles is almost 13G，and the tablespace only used 1%. Even if I truncated all the table,My datafiles is still not reduced.So I doubt weather the truncate cmd reset the hwm.

Comment: I think if I lower the hwm, then I can use the cmd **alter database datafile resize** to resize the datafiles.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, We find that we get a droped table in the end of the segment, so the hwm is high, we purge the tablespace , then alter table datefile resize.